# Trying to build a chart in C# wpf ,binding not happening in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, data-binding, charts

I am trying to build a column chart in wpf c# and i am use DataVisuializationTool Kit. I followed the procedure from this web link and did exactly it say. i have the data but the final binding is not happening. 
here is the link i followed::`http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/column-chart-in-wpf/`

```
   Here is my code.::
    ........................................................................


                        if (DG1_Liters > 0)
                        {
                            DG1_Liters = (DG1_Liters / DG_NUM_RECORDS_IN_THAT_HOUR) + ((DG1_C * DG_NUM_RECORDS_IN_THAT_HOUR) / 60);

                            dbCollection.Add(new VM.Chart.AxisData((startTime24), (Convert.ToInt32(DG1_Liters)), 0, 0));
                            shellVM.chartVM.MinimumVal = 0;
                            shellVM.chartVM.MaximumVal = 500;

                        }
                        if (DG2_Liters > 0)
                        {

                            DG2_Liters = (DG3_Liters / DG_NUM_RECORDS_IN_THAT_HOUR) + ((DG2_C * DG_NUM_RECORDS_IN_THAT_HOUR) / 60);
                            dbCollection.Add(new VM.Chart.AxisData((startTime24),0, (Convert.ToInt32(DG2_Liters)), 0));
                            shellVM.chartVM.MinimumVal = 0;
                            shellVM.chartVM.MaximumVal = 500;

                        }
                        if (DG3_Liters > 0)
                        {

                           DG3_Liters = (DG3_Liters / DG_NUM_RECORDS_IN_THAT_HOUR) + ((DG3_C * DG_NUM_RECORDS_IN_THAT_HOUR) / 60);
                            // dbCollection.Add(new VM.Chart.AxisData((startTime24),Convert.ToInt32(DG3_Liters)));
                            dbCollection.Add(new VM.Chart.AxisData((startTime24),0, 0 ,(Convert.ToInt32(DG3_Liters))));
                            shellVM.chartVM.MinimumVal = 0;
                            shellVM.chartVM.MaximumVal = 500;

                        }
                  }

               }

        }

 /*comment:: I am getting/setting some sets of data from AXIS clas property and storing it in a collection in DG3_Liters,DG1_Liters,DG2_Liters . 
       and finally creating the chart below.*/

    this.shellVM.chartVM.LineGraphTitle = "X Axis - Time \n\nY Axis - " + YAxis;  

    ((ColumnSeries)this.chart.chart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = dbCollection;
    ((ColumnSeries)this.chart.chart.Series[1]).ItemsSource = dbCollection;
    ((ColumnSeries)this.chart.chart.Series[2]).ItemsSource = dbCollection;
```

Here is my chart code

```
     ..............Chart.Xml...........
   d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
                xmlns:dv="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
                 xmlns:dvc="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ILS.VM.Chart;assembly=ILS.VM"
                 >
    <Grid>
        <dvc:Chart Name="chart">
            <dvc:Chart.Series>
                <dvc:ColumnSeries Title="DG 1"

                                  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Time}"
                                  DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=DG1}" />
                <dvc:ColumnSeries Title="DG 2"

                                  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Time}"
                                  DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=DG2}" />
                <dvc:ColumnSeries Title="DG 3"

                                  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Time}"
                                  DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=DG3}" />

            </dvc:Chart.Series>
        </dvc:Chart>
```

here is my axis class code property

```
public class AxisData
    {
        public AxisData(DateTime time, int DG1,int DG2,int DG3)
        {
            this.Time = time;
            this.DG1 = DG1;
            this.DG2 = DG2;
            this.DG3= DG3;
        }
        public DateTime Time
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int DG1
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int DG2
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int DG3
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

I get data in this form:: DG1=6 DG2=3 DG3=7 Time =system.time. and so on collection. i put that in the chart item source but no binding happens what am i missing. does chart needs another get/set property, if so how do i connect it. help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your class AxisData doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229614%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The implementation could look like this:

```
public class ObservableClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    private int _dG1;
    public int DG1
    {
        get { return _dG1; }
        set
        {
            _dG1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DG1");
        }
    }
}
```